# Deleting rows in a numpy array iteratively

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

My program needs to find the product of all the terms in a vector save for one row `i`, which is determined by a for loop. The `numpy.delete` function will not accept `i` as an input, only a number. Is there a workaround for this?

Example:

```
for i in range(some_range):
    arr=[some vector]
    section=np.delete(arr,i,axis=0)
    return prod(section)
```

This returns a `ValueError`: invalid entry message. The code works fine when I replace the `i` with 1. Is there any way to perform this operation while retaining the `for` loop?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? The way you have it here with the `return` inside the loop, it will only run once (making the loop pointless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to delete anything. Just multiply the two subproducts (the elements before `i` and the elements after `i`):

```
In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: arr = np.arange(1, 10)

In [12]: i = 3

In [13]: np.prod(arr[:i]) * np.prod(arr[i+1:])
Out[13]: 90720
```

Like with your original code, you need to make sure that `i` is a valid index (if you don't, you'd get the product of the entire array).